# Trouble adding images to when converting word document from HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

I'm trying to dynamically generate a word document on the client for a report.

I create a HTML string in the format:

```
<html xmlns:office="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:word="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
    <xml>
        <word:WordDocument>
        <word:View>Print</word:View>
        <word:Zoom>90</word:Zoom>
        <word:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
        </word:WordDocument>
    </xml>
    <style>Some CSS</style>
</head>
<body>
    Some HTML
</body>
```

And then base64 convert the HTML string and set the download attribute on an a to be "data:text/html,base64EncodedText"

This all works fine except that the images do not work.

I've tried:
    img src="https://hostname/imagepath",
    img src="data:image/png;base64encodeduri"
 and started trying to use a VML but have had no luck (the encoded srcs open fine when using them as a URL in the browser).

Can anyone help? What is the best way to get images into a word document?

If possible I'd like to avoid using a library, I've looked at docx.js but can't use it because of the licensing (and that there are no examples for it...).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've run into a similar problem while trying to convert html to a word document. Word cannot read images encoded in base64 and has a few limitations regarding css and image style properties.

I recommend following this [tutorial](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation). It is quite detailed when it comes to the way the data should be saved.

It should be noted that it will only work for files saved as .doc formats.